# DataGrid copy to clipboard with style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with a bunch of DataGridTextColumn columns. Some of them have CellStyle property set with a custom Style with <DataTrigger> elements that set the Background color of the cells based on their value.

It appears selecting a row and pressing Ctrl-C only copies the cell text to the clipboard, not the colors. So pasting it to programs like OneNote produces a table with black text, and no background colors are copied.

Is there a way to enable copying of the style as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to write something to do it yourself.

Here is the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,d5a0331c287f45ad) for the code that handles [ApplicationCommands.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the DataGrid, and on line 8252 are all the formats for which the copy is implemented.

```
Collection<string> formats = new Collection<string>(new string[] { DataFormats.Html, DataFormats.Text, DataFormats.UnicodeText, DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue });
```

and from visualstudio immediate window output we can see the result of ApplicationCommands.Copy on the DataGrid.

```
Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()
[0]: "CSV"
[1]: "Text"
[2]: "UnicodeText"
[3]: "System.String"
[4]: "HTML Format"
```

Out of those only HTML has any styling capabilities, but as of now the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridClipboardHelper.cs,fe17fc34b7b39244,references) only implements it to create an HTML Table.

You can however override the [DataGrid.OnExecutedCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onexecutedcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and implement copy in a format that supports styling yourself.